# They deleted a comment I responded, doesn't that create confusion to future readers?

Tags: support, comments

The situation is: I responded to a comment (In a question of mine in particular), pointing to a mistake in that comment. He then deleted his comment. Should I delete my responses? Should I wait until someone with big reputation cleans the comment clutter? Seems like commenting and deleting could create confusion and chaos. Shouldn't there be a system to clean those messes?

Comment: Why would there be confusion if you deleted your responses, given that the comment you're responding to isn't there anymore? Is it not more confusing to only see your response without the comment it's responding to?

Comment: @Servy I agree with your comment. When I say "Seems like commenting and deleting could create confusion and chaos" I refer to HE deleting, not me. My post tries to say this: If I delete my response, there is no confusion. The problem is that I don't get notified if someone deletes his comment obviously, so, how I'm going to delete my response if I don't know I should? I've left comments everywhere on stack exchange.

Comment: That's a completely different question then.  If you know what you should do when you realize a comment of yours is obsolete, then there's no reason to ask us what to do.  If you want to know how to *know* when a comment of yours is obsolete, I guess you could ask about that.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, now read my comment please.

Comment: Doesn't change my response.

Comment: Comments are deleted all the time.  Might be confusing to a new user, but you get used to the fact in a short time.

Comment: If somebody made a comment, and stated something that was incorrect and you pointed that mistake out, and the comment author realized you were right so they deleted the comment because they were wrong.  what's the problem?  Just delete your obsolete comment or don't and somebody will flag it eventually or perhaps they won't it's not a big deal comments are not that important

Answer (score 7):

Comments are meant to be temporary. Once they've outlived their usefulness they *should* be deleted.

Two obvious uses of the "obsolete" comment flag are that it indicates that the condition the comment was referencing is no longer valid, or that the comment to which it was replying no longer exists.

You should delete your comments if there's no reason for them to exist anymore. One time that may be is in the current circumstance: a different comment you replied to has been deleted.

When you see comments that are leftovers from some other apparent post-and-reply, simply use the flag tool to mark them "obsolete" and move on with your life.

As for it being confusing to future readers, who cares? Comments are "second-class citizens", as people like to say. At the end of the day, as long as the answers are useful and match the question, it doesn't matter what detritus is left in the comments.

Comment: while I completely agree with you that they should be deleted when "they've outlived their usefulness" (such as a reaction to deleted comment), I do not fully agree with "At the end of the day, as long as the answers are useful and match the question, it doesn't matter what detritus is left in the comments": I've gathered a lot of useful information from comments.

Answer (score 5):

Comments already exhibit (other) flaws that make them fall under the second-class citizen category. Even if they are helpful at times, they

- are prone to ad-hoc deletion, possibly removing contextual information;
- are discouraged when there are too many;
- are shortened in what is displayed to a visitor based on score (while they can expand to view all comments); and
- may point to non-existent @-mentions if users are removed (or comments are deleted).

In the past I've flagged comments related to my comment deletion as obsolete if the removal of those comments doesn't take away any value. This somehow leaves the onus on the user who deletes their comment, and invariably will lead to some people complaining that their comments are being deleted without their knowledge. However, with the community in mind, this may be one option to follow.

As for your concern in terms of confusion: Don't be. Clean up what confuses you and it will most likely help others as well.